# Equivalent for this input[type="submit"] in javascript

Tags: javascript

In jQuery there is a way to select the submit button like this:

```
$('input[type="submit"]');
```

Is there any equivalent in plain Javascript?

Comment: Give the `<input type="submit" />` an ID for easier selection, so you can access it directly, else you'll have to transverse the document either via the `<form>` or.. many other ways! =]

Comment: No I have many pages to do. I want to select directly without any id or class

Comment: Well in that case you'd have to do `var getForms = document.forms;` and loop through and find the `input.type == 'submit'`s because in @madarauchiha's answer, you're still providing the same convention that an Class or ID does - by 'selecting' by a name. There's almost no difference. That or by going by `document.forms[0]` which is a horribly un generic method..

Answer (score 3):

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]');
```

See the [support list](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll), the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) and the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll).

… but that is no more "plain JavaScript" than using jQuery. It avoids using JavaScript functions written by a third party, but still uses the DOM API that browsers provide.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

- `document.forms["formName"]["nameOfSubmitButton"]` (assuming both form and submit button have a `name` attribute).
- The **[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll)** method, note that it doesn't work on IE7 or less.

Comment: Just to note, `document.forms["formName"]["nameOfSubmitButton"]` will access **a** form, whilst I'm sure you understand that `$('input[type="submit"]');` will of course retrieve _many_ elements, if any.

Comment: @MackieeE: He implied there's only one by referring to it as "*The* submit button". So I included it.